# Test coverage of print functions in R package

Tags: r, code-coverage, testthat

I have a simple print function in an R package:

```
print.tabyl <- function(x){
  print.data.frame(x, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

I'm trying to achieve full test coverage of my package and it annoys me that my untested print function lowers my test coverage to 99% (it would be 100% otherwise).

But I can't figure out how to capture of the output of the print function in order to write a test for it.  How can I write a test for a print function?

Comment: Have you seen the function `expect_output()` in the `testthat` package? I use it in my repositories to test plot output: `expect_output(print.tabyl(your_object))`

Comment: or wrap it in `capture.output`, which then returns strings of the lines printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the suggestion from @alistaire, I used `capture.output` to write a test:

```
test_that("print.tabyl prints without row numbers", {
  expect_equal(
    mtcars %>% tabyl(am, cyl) %>% capture.output(),
    c(" am 4 6  8", "  0 3 4 12", "  1 8 3  2")
  )
})
```

This captures that the `row.names` are missing; this result is different than `capture.output(print.data.frame(mtcars %>% tabyl(am, cyl)))` which still has the row numbers.

Using `capture.output` both tests the function and counts toward coverage on codecov.io's tracking.